# Linked list stack simulating a queue isn't working

Tags: c++, linked-list, queue, stack

My teacher, before we use queue<>, want us to use linked list stack like it was a queue with * first and *push. When I try to run them, they fail before the assert when I call the front or back. But the list is deleted has many number has there is.

Can somebody tell me were is my problem in this code?

the ==

```
#include "Client.h"
#include <iostream>

Client::Client(unsigned int clientID, string firstName, string surName)
{
    this->clientID = clientID;
    this->firstName = firstName;
    this->surName = surName;
}

Client::~Client()
{
}

void Client::writeClientInfo()
{
    cout << "Client number " << clientID <<": " <<firstName <<" " << surName <<endl;
}

bool Client::operator==(const Client& clientCoteDroit) const
{
    if (this->clientID == clientCoteDroit.clientID) 
    {
        if (this->firstName == clientCoteDroit.firstName)
        {
            if (this->surName == clientCoteDroit.surName)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

List class

```
#include "ClientList.h"
ClientList::ClientList()
{
    this->first = nullptr;
    this->last = nullptr;
    this->nbElements = 0;
}

ClientList::~ClientList()
{
    while (!isEmpty())
    {
        pop();
    }
}

void ClientList::push(const Client& client)
{
    ClientNode* ptrClient = new ClientNode(client);
    if (isEmpty()) {
        this->first = ptrClient;
        this->last = ptrClient;
    }
    else
    {
        last->setNext(ptrClient);
        last = ptrClient;
    }
    nbElements++;
}

void ClientList::pop()
{
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw EmptyList();
    }

    ClientNode* tempNodel;
    tempNodel = first;
    if (first == last) 
    {
        first = last = nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        first = first->getNext();
    }
    delete tempNodel;
    nbElements--;
}

Client ClientList::front() const
{
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        throw EmptyList();
    }
    return *first->getClient();
}

Client ClientList::back() const
{
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        throw EmptyList();
    }
    return *last->getClient();
}

bool ClientList::isEmpty() const
{
    return (first == nullptr && last == nullptr);
}

int ClientList::size() const
{
    return nbElements;
}
```

test

```
        TEST_METHOD(Lorsqu_on_ajoute_un_element_dans_une_ClientList_vide_l_element_ajoute_est_present_au_debut)
        {
            //Arange
            ClientList clientList;
            Client client1(1, "Generic", "Man");

            //Action
            clientList.push(client1);

            //Assert
            Client client2 = clientList.front();
            Assert::IsTrue(client1 == client2);
        }
        
        TEST_METHOD(Lorsqu_on_ajoute_un_element_dans_une_ClientList_vide_l_element_ajoute_est_present_a_la_fin)
        {
            //Arange
            ClientList clientList;
            Client client1(1, "Generic", "Man");

            //Action
            clientList.push(client1);

            //Assert
            Client client2 = clientList.back();
            Assert::IsTrue(client1 == client2);
        }
        
        TEST_METHOD(Lorsqu_on_ajoute_un_element_dans_une_ClientList_non_vide_l_element_ajoute_est_present_a_la_fin)
        {
            //Arange
            ClientList clientList; //Ce test ne demande pas de modification du code de LinkedListStack!
            Client client1(1, "Generic", "Man");
            Client client2(2, "Generic", "Woman");
            clientList.push(client1);
            
            //Action
            clientList.push(client2);

            //Assert
            Client client3 = clientList.back();
            Assert::IsTrue(client2 == client3);
        }
        
        TEST_METHOD(Lorsqu_on_ajoute_un_element_dans_une_ClientList_non_vide_le_premier_element_ajoute_est_au_debut)
        {
            //Arange
            ClientList clientList; //Ce test ne demande pas de modification du code de LinkedListStack!
            Client client1(1, "Generic", "Man");
            Client client2(2, "Generic", "Woman");
            clientList.push(client1);

            //Action
            clientList.push(client2);

            //Assert
            Client client3 = clientList.front();
            Assert::IsTrue(client1 == client3);
        }
```

Comment: What is a `ClientNode`? [Edit] the question to include a [mre], including the class definitions for your classes.

Comment: #include "ClientNode.h"
ClientNode::ClientNode(Client client)
{
    setClient(client);
    setNext(nullptr);
}

ClientNode::~ClientNode()
{
    while()
}

ClientNode* ClientNode::getNext()
{
    return this->next;
}

void ClientNode::setNext(ClientNode* next)
{
    this->next = next;
}

//Retourne le contenu de cet élément.
Client* ClientNode::getClient()
{
    return client;
}

//Change la contenu de cet élément.
void ClientNode::setClient(Client& client)
{
    ClientNode clientTemp = new ClientNode(client);
}

But I don't know I should define the new in set.

Comment: Not in comment... please *edit* your question.